# Compare string with character in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

suppose there is a string like this

```
string temp2 = "hello";
char[] m = { 'u','i','o' };

Boolean B = temp2.Compare(m);
```

I want to check if the string contains my array of character or not?
I am trying but it is not taking.On compiling the message

> temp2.Compare(m) should be String type

is coming.
Means it follows string.compare(string);
I hope it is not the way there should be some way to do that.

edit//

I have Corrected the line String.Compare return the Boolean Value

Comment: So it's Java or C#? Edit either question header or tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to determine is whether the string contains *any* of the characters in your array, you can use the [`string.IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) function.

```
bool containsAny = temp2.IndexOfAny(m) >= 0;
```

Comment: your correct.. it would have to be looped thru sorry about that Adam my eyes saw string[]